# I need to use the scikit-image module for my project, but it always gives the error "No module named 'skimage'"

Tags: python, spyder, scikit-image

I write my project on windows using spyder and when i import scikit-image i get error.

I imported it like this:

```
from skimage import data,io,filters,color,segmentation, img_as_float
```

Here is the installed python and its modules information:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> python --version
Python 3.9.10
PS C:\Windows\system32> pip list
Package       Version
------------- ---------
imageio       2.18.0
joblib        1.1.0
networkx      2.8
numpy         1.22.3
packaging     21.3
Pillow        9.1.0
pip           22.0.4
pyparsing     3.0.8
PyWavelets    1.3.0
scikit-image  0.19.2
scikit-learn  1.0.2
scipy         1.8.0
setuptools    58.1.0
threadpoolctl 3.1.0
tifffile      2022.4.28
```

Here is the error massage:

```
line 8, in <module>
from skimage import data,io,filters,color,segmentation, img_as_float
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skimage'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  How did you install scikit-image?

Comment: thanks ! i just pip install scikit-image at CMD. I tried reinstalling everything except python but still couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: I'm trying right now. thanks for the advice.

Comment: Error message changed finally some progress :D 

cannot import name 'geometry' from 'skimage._shared' (C:\Users\hcasl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\skimage\_shared\__init__.py)
It seems that scikit-image has not been built correctly.

Comment: If you are using Spyder through the standalone installer you will need to use the custom interpreter preference to point to the correct interpreter. Maybe a look to the Spyder docs FAQ page could help: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html